# How to combine lists and dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, automation

With Python I am trying to retrieve a list of recipients from MySQL8 which will receive alerts via email. Now I am struggling how to cycle through lists (or dict) and pull all that data together.

Pseudo Code with minimal example:

```
recipients = []

recipients.append({
  "ID": 1,
  "name": "Mustang",
  "email": "bla@blub.de"
})

recipients.append({
  "ID": 2,
  "name": "Ford",
  "email": "na@nub.de"
})

products = []
for recipient in recipients:
    # get products for this recipient. pseudo MySQL
    # select ... from ... 
    # WHERE 
    #    manufacturer_id = recipient['ID']
    products.append({
      "MANUFACTURER_ID" : recipient['ID'],
        "ARTICLE_ID": 88,
      "STATUS": "available"
    })    

for recipient in recipients:
    
    print('Send to: ', recipient)
    for product in products:
        print('Message: ', product)
    print('Sending...')
```

The expected result should be that each recipient only gets the info for his manufacturer_id. The example does not work as expected.

Here is the orginal code with SQL and other elements.

This code will save the recipients within a list:

```
try:
    """ get recipients
    """
    recipients = []
    curb = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
    curb.execute("""
        SELECT
            MANUFACTURER_ID,
            EMAIL,
            NAME
        FROM manufacturers_alerts_recipients
        """)
    results = curb.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        recipients.append([row[0], row[1], row[2]])
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to fetch recipients for alerts - MySQL Error {}".format(error))
curb.close()

print(recipients)
```

Now I am trying to get all alerts for each recipient with a second query:

```
try:
    if recipients:
        for recipient in recipients:
            """ get changes in availability
            """
            curb = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
            curb.execute("""
                SELECT
                       TITLE,
                       ARTICLE_ID,
                       NAME,
                       AVAILABILITY
                FROM merchants_product_catalog
                WHERE 
                    manufacturer_id = %s
                """, (
                recipient[0]
            )
            )
            results = curb.fetchall()
            for row in results:
                products.append([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]])
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to fetch availability - MySQL Error {}".format(error))

curb.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Then sending:

```
for recipient in recipients:
        BODY_TXT = '''{availability_list} '''.format(availability_list=tabulate(recipient, headers=['PRODUCT', 'SKU', 'POS', 'AVAILABILITY'))
```

I believe there are several conceptual flaws with this code as I am new to Phyton. What would be the best to achive the desired functionality? Dict? Lists?

Comment: Some test data would be nice. What is the result of BODY_TXT?

Comment: It is a simple table with the changes retrieved from the second query.

Comment: @user56700 I just added a minimal example to the question including sample data.